# merge elements in a list according to another list

Tags: r, list, merge

I have the following list:

```
L = list()

L[[1]] = c(1,2,3)
L[[2]] = c(4,5)
L[[3]] = c(6,7,8)
L[[4]] = c(9, 10, 11, 12, 13)
L[[5]] = c(14, 15, 16)
```

I would like to merge specific elements of `L` according to values given in the list `ToUnite`:

```
ToUnite = list()
ToUnite[[1]] = c(1,2,3)
ToUnite[[2]] = c(4,5)
```

So that the resulting list should contain two elements, corresponding to c(1,2,3) and c(4,5) of `L`, respectively, looking like this:

```
result = list()
result[[1]] = seq(1,8)
result[[2]] = seq(9, 16)
```

How can I do this in the most efficient way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can loop through 'ToUnite' with `lapply`,  extract the `list` elements of 'L' and `unlist`

```
lapply(ToUnite, function(x) unlist(L[x]))
#[[1]]
# [1] 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8

#[[2]]
# [1]  9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16
```